# Handle event in Xamarin Forms when variable change with hardware keyboard

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

With this method I intercept the keystrokes in the physical keyboard of the device (in the MainActivity.cs file)

```
public override bool OnKeyUp(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (keyCode.ToString().Equals("DpadLeft"))
            {
                App.Left = true;
                App.Right = false;
            }
            else if (keyCode.ToString().Equals("DpadRight"))
            {
                App.Left = false;
                App.Right = true;
            }
            else
            {
                App.Left = false;
                App.Right = false;
            }
            return base.OnKeyUp(keyCode, e);
        }
```

In my application I would like to change the value from false to true shots a specific event (now linked to the pressure of the button)
For example, this is the event in my ContentPage

```
PreviousButton.Clicked += (s, e) => 
            {
                OnPreviousClickedAsync(s, e);
            };
NextButton.Clicked += (s, e) => 
            {
                OnNextClickedAsync(s, e);
            };
```

Is there a way to create a global event that triggers the event when the value of the Left or Right variable is changed?

Answer (score 2):

You can either create an event at application-level for instance or use the `MessagingCenter`. With the [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) you can send a message whenever an event occurs. In another part of your application, you can subscribe to that message and execute logic.

To subscribe and act on a message:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "Hi", (sender) => {
    // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
});
```

To send a message:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "Hi");
```

You can send parameters if you want to. Check the documentation page for more advanced usages.

Comment: ContentPage has no method called OnKeyUp and in the ContentPage I can not use MessagingCenter.Subscribe <MainActivity> (this, "Hi", (sender) => {
    // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
});